# Removing Unnecessary Space from Equations within Custom Environments in thmtools

Tags: theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I'm facing an issue while writing my thesis. Whenever a theorem ends with an equation, an additional line is added. I have to use `thmtools`, and I'm unsure whether I should remove this space from the `theorem` environment definition or if it needs to be addressed elsewhere. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    postheadspace=1em, %Space after dot.
    qed={},
]{Theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=Theorem, name=Theorem]{theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    This is the most beautiful equation
    \begin{align*}
        e^{i\pi}+1=0.
    \end{align*}
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theorem}
    Possibly, the equation
    \begin{align*}
        E=mc^2
    \end{align*}
    was ahead of its time.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Why do you use `align*` environments for single-line displayed equations?

Comment: I was just trying something different, but $$ doesn't work either.

Comment: Never use `$$` in LaTeX documents.

Comment: Should I use `equation` enviroment?

Comment: By the way, why not?

Comment: Please read [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Comment: I can replicate the issue you've come across, even when replacing `align*` with `equation*`. Is there any way you could make to without the machinery of the `thmtools` package and, instead, rely on the machinery of the `amsthm` package to create suitable theorem-like environments?

Comment: What I like the most of `thmtools` is that you can customize the qed symbol of definitions, examples ant theorems. I think this is would be cumbersome in `amsthm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the key `qed={}` which is telling thmtools to insert an empty qed symbol. This comes at the line underneath the equation, hence the extra line. You can see this in the simple example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}
\sum
\end{equation}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: testthm]

So just remove the `qed={}` from `\declaretheoremstyle` and the line disappears.